# How can I search for data in a flat file

Tags: php

I have done some bits but please can you help me with this

```
?php 
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $file =(file_get_contents("data.txt"));
  if (strstr($file, "$username .'   '.$password)"){
  }

?>
```

With this code, I am trying to read what is in the file which is username and password but it isn't working.

Thanks you

Here is the form

#### MY ACCOUNT

```
<form action = "wacc.php" method = "POST">
<tr>
<td>Username:</br><input type="text" name="username"></br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</br><input type="password" name="password"></br></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align = "center"><input type="submit"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Typo am sure. Just for the record, missing `<` in `?php` in your question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although using plain text for a login script is **highly discouraged**, the use of a DB is safer.

Here is a solution.

(Pre-tested)

If using a comma as a seperator, use the following for your data.txt file.

`user1,password1`
`user2,password2`
`user3,password3`

The seperator must match the one in the PHP handler (below).

I.e. (comma) `"$username,$password"`

### Handler

```
<?php 
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $file = file_get_contents("data.txt");

if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
die("You must enter both your username and password to continue.");
}

if(!strstr($file, "$username,$password")) {
echo "Sorry, try again.";
  }

else {
echo "You have access.";
}

?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. If this helped and fixed your problem, then click on the white checkmark next to my question till it turns green, so we can close the question properly. Otherwise, it will remain in the unanswered category. @jibs91

Answer (score 0):

You're messing up your single, double quotes and () in the `strstr`-line. It should be something like this.

```
strstr($file, $username .'   '.$password)
```

Comment: Thanks but when I tried it, it show some error messages saying Undefined: username and Undefined: password.

Comment: Are you using a form in conjunction with your PHP? @jibs91 and if so, add it to your question so we can see.

Comment: Then add it to your question so we can see if something doesn't match or has not been properly named. @jibs91

Comment: You did change `if (strstr($file, "$username .'   '.$password)"){` to `if (strstr($file, $username .'   '.$password)){` right? @jibs91 your code (kind of) checks out, as does your form, so I don't know why you're getting an `Undefined` error message. Did you reload your code/page, cleared your cache?

Comment: Plus just for the record (from a comment I put a while ago), missing `<` in `?php` in your question. @jibs91

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh that was when I was trying to post the question but thanks though

Comment: How is your `data.txt` structured as? As in what type of seperator are you using? I.e. `user1||password1` @jibs91 or with a comma `user1,password1` ?